# Переадресация в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Как сделать, чтобы при заходе на адрес **http://site.ru/system/user.php** автоматически переадресовывало на **http://site.ru/user.php**?

```
RewriteRule ^user.php$ /system/user.php [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^system/user\.php$ /user.php [R=301,L]
```